# Convert DSA asymmetric key in .NET XML format to PEM format

Tags: c#, php, .net, cryptography, openssl

I have a `DSA` private key exported using the `DSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString`, and I need to convert it to `PEM` format ("*file.pem*"), so I can open it in `PHP` using `openssl_pkey_get_private` function.

How do I accomplish this?

The solution can use `DSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob` method if it's of any help, I just need to convert the key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the bouncycastle C# library class `DotNetUtilities`, it is fairly easy.

```
DSACryptoServiceProvider dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair dsaKey = DotNetUtilities.GetDsaKeyPair(dsa);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("dsa.pem"))
{
    PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw);
    pw.WriteObject(dsaKey);
}
```

Comment: +1, I'm just surprised there is no direct way how to do that using pure .NET framework only (no additional external libraries).

Comment: Well, the PEM format is not a real standard, more a de-facto one.

Comment: Running this exact code using .NET 4.5 and the latest BouncyCastle from NuGet (1.7.0), I get a StackOverflowException when calling pw.WriteObject(dsaKey).  I also tried using .NET 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0, same issue.  Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Solution: revert to the 1.6.1 release.  No more StackOverflowException.

Comment: @Oran: File a bug report at the bouncycastle.org. Thanks.